# django inlineformset_factory, view changed fields on save

Tags: django, django-views

I am creating some custom validation, that on save checks if certain fields values have changed.

On `POST`, is there a way in the `view` that I can check what fields have changed for that formset?

I am currently looping through the formset and am able to view individual field values, so I could compare them to a query. It just seems to be a bit more than necessary considering the formset doesn't go through the save process if nothing has changed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to your formset:

```
def has_changed()
    return all([form.has_changed() for form in self.forms])
```

Similarly, the form also documents the changed_fields, which you can concatenate in your formset.

I don't think `formset.save()` blindly overwrites all entries into the db. It checks the changed forms, which I think is available in `formset.changed_forms` and it updates only those rows in the db.

Comment: I don't think I am following your explanation correctly. I can't find anything in the Django docs or in the code for `changed_forms` or `changed_fields`. Could you explain this a bit more?